# Difficulty receiving Json Form-Data Through PostMan

Tags: php, json, postman

While receiving data on PHP file code is like -

```php
print_r($_POST);
echo $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

I am getting null array

[image]

How to get the value while posting ? Here is the headers I used

[image]

Comment: Just to test, replace your code (print_r, echo..) with: `phpinfo(32);` and send the request through Postman again. You should see the variables in the listing..

Answer (score 0):

use `x-www-form-urlencoded` while posting data.Then

```
echo json_encode($_POST);//prints into json format
```

Try it will works.

**NOTE:** By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content- type, "application/json". When we want to post the value as a FORM post, we need to change the serialization algorithm and post the data with the content-type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".